# How can I list the available video modes for a USB webcam in Linux?

Tags: linux, usb, webcam

I faintly recall that once upon a time, I found a command-line tool (something involving "UVC") to list the supported resolutions & modes of a USB webcam camera (e.g. PAL, 640x480) in Linux, but alas, I've lost it. Does anyone know what I'm talking about? I want something that will give something like,

```
> list-uvc-modes /dev/video1
PAL, YUYV, 640x480, 30 FPS
NTSC, MJPEG, ...
```

Thanks!

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/214977/how-can-i-find-out-the-supported-webcam-resolutions

Comment: This [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1204892/989186) is also really good

Answer (score 53, accepted):

If you have `v4l` (video 4 linux 2) installed you can do:

```
v4l2-ctl --list-formats
```

Comment: Cool, I did `v4l2-ctl -d /dev/video2 --list-formats` and then `v4l2-ctl -d /dev/video2 --list-framesizes=YUYV`. It seems v4l2-ctl has a lot more options too. Thanks very much!

Comment: Even more details with `v4l2-ctl --list-formats-ext`

Comment: On my laptop, only  `--list-formats-ext` works.   The option `--list-formats` does not show the resolution.

Answer (score 6):

The accepted answer (`v4l2-ctl --list-formats`) seems to show only the first available format, e.g.:

```
$ v4l2-ctl --list-formats
ioctl: VIDIOC_ENUM_FMT
        Index       : 0
        Type        : Video Capture
        Pixel Format: ''
        Name        : 2036315a-0000-0010-8000-00aa003

        Index       : 1
        Type        : Video Capture
        Pixel Format: ''
        Name        : 00000050-0000-0010-8000-00aa003
```

**To see *all* available formats, you may want to use a script along similar to the following:**

```
$ for d in /dev/video* ; do echo $d ; v4l2-ctl --device=$d -D --list-formats  ; echo '===============' ; done
/dev/video0
Driver Info (not using libv4l2):
        Driver name   : uvcvideo
        Card type     : Intel(R) RealSense(TM) 410
        Bus info      : usb-0000:00:14.0-1
        Driver version: 4.4.13
        Capabilities  : 0x84200001
                Video Capture
                Streaming
                Extended Pix Format
                Device Capabilities
        Device Caps   : 0x04200001
                Video Capture
                Streaming
                Extended Pix Format
ioctl: VIDIOC_ENUM_FMT
        Index       : 0
        Type        : Video Capture
        Pixel Format: 'Z16 '
        Name        : Depth data 16-bit (Z16)

        Index       : 1
        Type        : Video Capture
        Pixel Format: ''
        Name        : 00000050-0000-0010-8000-00aa003

===============
/dev/video1
Driver Info (not using libv4l2):
        Driver name   : uvcvideo
        Card type     : Intel(R) RealSense(TM) 410
        Bus info      : usb-0000:00:14.0-1
        Driver version: 4.4.13
        Capabilities  : 0x84200001
                Video Capture
                Streaming
                Extended Pix Format
                Device Capabilities
        Device Caps   : 0x04200001
                Video Capture
                Streaming
                Extended Pix Format
ioctl: VIDIOC_ENUM_FMT
        Index       : 0
        Type        : Video Capture
        Pixel Format: ''
        Name        : 00000032-0000-0010-8000-00aa003

        Index       : 1
        Type        : Video Capture
        Pixel Format: 'UYVY'
        Name        : UYVY 4:2:2

        Index       : 2
        Type        : Video Capture
        Pixel Format: 'Y8I '
        Name        : Greyscale 8 L/R (Y8I)

        Index       : 3
        Type        : Video Capture
        Pixel Format: 'Y12I'
        Name        : Greyscale 12 L/R (Y12I)

===============
$ v4l2-ctl -D -d /dev/video1 --list-formats-ext
Driver Info (not using libv4l2):
        Driver name   : uvcvideo
        Card type     : Intel(R) RealSense(TM) 410
        Bus info      : usb-0000:00:14.0-1
        Driver version: 4.4.13
        Capabilities  : 0x84200001
                Video Capture
                Streaming
                Extended Pix Format
                Device Capabilities
        Device Caps   : 0x04200001
                Video Capture
                Streaming
                Extended Pix Format
ioctl: VIDIOC_ENUM_FMT
        Index       : 0
        Type        : Video Capture
        Pixel Format: ''
        Name        : 00000032-0000-0010-8000-00aa003
                Size: Discrete 424x240
                        Interval: Discrete 0.011s (90.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.017s (60.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.167s (6.000 fps)
                Size: Discrete 480x270
                        Interval: Discrete 0.011s (90.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.017s (60.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.167s (6.000 fps)
                Size: Discrete 640x360
                        Interval: Discrete 0.011s (90.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.017s (60.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.167s (6.000 fps)
                Size: Discrete 640x480
                        Interval: Discrete 0.011s (90.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.017s (60.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.167s (6.000 fps)
                Size: Discrete 848x480
                        Interval: Discrete 0.011s (90.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.017s (60.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.167s (6.000 fps)
                Size: Discrete 1280x720
                        Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.167s (6.000 fps)

        Index       : 1
        Type        : Video Capture
        Pixel Format: 'UYVY'
        Name        : UYVY 4:2:2
                Size: Discrete 424x240
                        Interval: Discrete 0.011s (90.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.017s (60.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.167s (6.000 fps)
                Size: Discrete 480x270
                        Interval: Discrete 0.011s (90.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.017s (60.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.167s (6.000 fps)
                Size: Discrete 640x360
                        Interval: Discrete 0.011s (90.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.017s (60.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.167s (6.000 fps)
                Size: Discrete 640x480
                        Interval: Discrete 0.011s (90.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.017s (60.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.167s (6.000 fps)
                Size: Discrete 848x480
                        Interval: Discrete 0.011s (90.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.017s (60.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.167s (6.000 fps)
                Size: Discrete 1280x720
                        Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.167s (6.000 fps)

        Index       : 2
        Type        : Video Capture
        Pixel Format: 'Y8I '
        Name        : Greyscale 8 L/R (Y8I)
                Size: Discrete 424x240
                        Interval: Discrete 0.011s (90.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.017s (60.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.167s (6.000 fps)
                Size: Discrete 480x270
                        Interval: Discrete 0.011s (90.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.017s (60.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.167s (6.000 fps)
                Size: Discrete 640x360
                        Interval: Discrete 0.011s (90.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.017s (60.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.167s (6.000 fps)
                Size: Discrete 640x480
                        Interval: Discrete 0.011s (90.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.017s (60.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.167s (6.000 fps)
                Size: Discrete 848x480
                        Interval: Discrete 0.011s (90.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.017s (60.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.167s (6.000 fps)
                Size: Discrete 1280x720
                        Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.167s (6.000 fps)
                Size: Discrete 1920x1080
                        Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)

        Index       : 3
        Type        : Video Capture
        Pixel Format: 'Y12I'
        Name        : Greyscale 12 L/R (Y12I)
                Size: Discrete 960x540
                        Interval: Discrete 0.040s (25.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
                Size: Discrete 1920x1080
                        Interval: Discrete 0.040s (25.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
```

Comment: `--list-formats-ext` seems easier than a script

Answer (score 4):

If you use uvc controls for a webcam, another method is :

```
uvcdynctrl -f
```

You can also do :

```
uvcdynctrl -l
```

to list all the devices.

Answer (score 3):

With `ffmpeg`:

```
ffmpeg -f v4l2 -list_formats all -i /dev/video0
```

([documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-devices.html#video4linux2_002c-v4l2))

Example output:

```
$ ffmpeg -f v4l2 -list_formats all -i /dev/video0
ffmpeg version 4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-10ubuntu2)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=1ubuntu0.1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/aarch64-linux-gnu --arch=arm64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
  libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
  libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
  libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
  libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
  libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
  libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
[video4linux2,v4l2 @ 0xaaaae89c8460] Raw       :     yuyv422 :           YUYV 4:2:2 : 640x360
[video4linux2,v4l2 @ 0xaaaae89c8460] Compressed:       mjpeg :          Motion-JPEG : 640x360 1280x720 1920x1080 3840x2160
[video4linux2,v4l2 @ 0xaaaae89c8460] Compressed:        h264 :                H.264 : 640x360 1280x720 1920x1080 3840x2160
/dev/video0: Immediate exit requested
```

(notice there is no information regarding supported framerates)

Example for using this information to grab a 10 second h264-based 1920x1080 stream capture to output file `output.h264`:

```
ffmpeg -f v4l2 -input_format h264 -video_size 1920x1080 -i /dev/video0 -t 10 -acodec copy -vcodec copy output.h264
```

To playback this capture:

```
ffplay output.h264
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use C/C++ [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22563827/list-available-capture-formats) to get list formats. Sorry code from link above is deprecated but my reputation is too low to edit it. But you can use this modern [code](https://github.com/AndreiCherniaev/V4L2_list-formats).

Comment: Link only answers are not recommended,  because the links may disappear. It would be better if you included relevant information in your answer.

Comment: @RohitGupta,
Code above hosted in github and it is Included in the GitHub Archive Program.